# Regex to find number that follow a keyword

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to capture number within text that is being followed by a key word 'amount'

`preg_match_all("/amount.+\b(\d+(\.\d+)?)/im", $input_lines, $output_array);`

my input data is

```
here is some number 100.25
that does not 200.
but this amount should be captured 300.
and this amount should be captured 400.25 too
and this amount should be captured $5023 too
and this amount should be captured $60.25 too
and this amount should be captured 700.25.

But not this amount 800.25.2
```

so only the numbers 300, 400.25, 5023, 60.25, 700.25 should be captured

Comment: I think I figured out what you wanted, but you should really explain the logic behind which numbers should and shouldn't match.

Answer (score 2):

The regex you are looking for is: `amount\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\.?(?!\d)`

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/iXwM40/1

This relies on there being no numbers between the word 'amount' and the set of numbers.

The key to this is the final set of brackets which is known as a negative lookahead: `(?!\d)` this will not match if the following character is a numeric digit. `\d`

See more info on lookaheads here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
$input_lines = "here is some number 100.25
that does not 200.
but this amount should be captured 300.
and this amount should be captured 400.25 too
and this amount should be captured $5023 too
and this amount should be captured $60.25 too
and this amount should be captured 700.25.

But not this amount 800.25.2";

preg_match_all("/(?:amount [^\d]+?)\K\d+(\.\d+)?/m", $input_lines, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:
Array

```
(
    [0] => 300
    [1] => 400.25
    [2] => 5023
    [3] => 60.25
    [4] => 700.25
)
```

---

`(?:amount [^\d]+?)` - matches strings(lines) with `amount` followed by any characters except numbers

`\K` - resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

`\d+(\.\d+)?` - matches the needed number(including decimal part if it's float number)

Comment: Without a look ahead (as in my answer) it would still capture the number on the final line as soon as it has another character between the word amount and the number. See here: https://regex101.com/r/i4uiEj/1 - I like the use of \K though :)

Comment: @Theo, that's not the input that the OP posted, it's different. Otherwise, the OP should clarify such cases

Comment: I agree OP could have been clearer (the first thing I did was comment that) - but those are clearly examples, and this is clearly going to be run on different input.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try `\bamount\b.*?(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

```
 \b amount \b .*? 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
```